# How to add headers using KStreams API (Java)

Tags: apache-kafka

How to add header using KStream API (Java).

Comment: What have you tried? Can you post some code?

Comment: I tested using Producer API as below, but how headers can be added using KStream API. 

                                                                         
ProducerRecord<String, String> record = new  ProducerRecord<String, String>("topic", "Key", "value");
        record.headers().add(new RecordHeader("A", "A".getBytes()));
        record.headers().add(new RecordHeader("B", "A".getBytes()));